# WatchKit how to make a phone call

Tags: watchkit

I am programming WatchKit, I would like to know how to make a phone call in watch kit extension? If it is impossible, how can I make the phone make a phone call by itself.

Comment: Do you have any code already? What problems are you running into?

Answer (score 2):

Apple advises to use Handoff instead.

The openParantApplication method + openURL will not work if the device is locked or the app is in background.